# Angular Filter Custom Search with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an search box i want the filter to check both skuname and osname same time but while searching single filed its working fine i want to search with this two combination

```
<input type="text" class=" search-query form-control" ng-model="lansearch" placeholder="Search" />

<tr ng-repeat-start="detail in details | filter:  lansearch ">
<td  >
<div style="margin-top:5px">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-bind="(detail.skuname)+'' +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'' +(detail.osname)"> </a>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the object you want to look for, like this: This will work like and AND operator.

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:  {skuname: lansearch, osname: lansearch} ">
```

Another option could be a function instead:

- Inside your controller:

  ```
  $scope.filterFunction= function(user){
      return user.skuname=== $scope.lansearch|| 
          user.osname=== $scope.lansearch;
  };
  ```

And then add the filter function in your html:

```
 ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:  filterFunction
```

Comment: <tr ng-repeat-start="detail in details | filter:  {skuname:value, osname:value} ">  you mean to say value as ng-model of search ie landsearch ? @Manuel Obregozo but its not working

Comment: Right, Please check another solution, I updated the answer.